# Responsive design for all android devices

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, responsive-design

I am using two different methods to achieve responsive design in android devices

**Method 1.** I used different **dimens.xml** in different folders like

```
values-hdpi
values-ldpi
values-mdpi
values-xhdpi  
values-xxhdpi
```

---

**Method 2.** I copied all my layouts to

```
layout
layout-large
layout-small
layout-xlarge
```

folders and given different heights, widths and other

When I use the first method I am not getting the correct responsive design and when I use the second method I am getting the correct design but it increasing the application size.

So, please tell me the best process to achieve 100% responsive design other than my two methods

Answer (score 2):

I usually go for the `values`, `values-large`, ... folders and put `dimens.xml` files there, where I specify the sizes for each screen size category. The `values` is the "fallback", it contains the default value if I don't specify any for a specific size category.
In the layouts I use it like this:

```
android:width="@dimen/width_for_this_view"
```

Defined in the `values/dimens.xml`:

```
<dimen name="width_for_this_view">30dp</dimen>
```

You can define different sizes for different `values` (large, normal, small, ..) folder.

Comment: Hi, i used values-large, values-normal, values-small previously but i did't get correct design for all devices. I think you are using more than these three folders (large, normal, small) can you tell me the other folder names

Comment: I use `normal, large, xlarge` for the main categories. I also use `land` for landscape mode, and you can also prepare for `long` for wide devices. You can find more details about the qualifiers here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use google library `PercentRelativeLayout` with this library you can set **width**, **height** and **margin** of your `views` by **percentage** which is great because in all screen they look the same and of course it is not hard to code it. Here example:

```
<android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
     <ImageView
         app:layout_widthPercent="50%"
         app:layout_heightPercent="50%"
         app:layout_marginTopPercent="25%"
         app:layout_marginLeftPercent="25%"/>
 </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>
```

you must add this line in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
}
```

**Official documentation by Google** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html

Hope this help for your case!

Comment: Hi, i'm using the eclipse for this project. If you don't mind can you tell me the process for eclipse

Comment: hmm this is gona be a hard for me beacuse i didnt imported in eclipse :/

Comment: Ho k :-( , i'll check for that

Comment: Here is the library https://github.com/JulienGenoud/android-percent-support-lib-sample but dont know exactly the steps for setting it up to your eclipse project.. PS... Just use Android Studio its Better ;)