# Calculator UI for different screen sizes

Tags: android

I am new in android. I am working on a calculator but I face a problem. The UI looks good in an android studio but when I run it on Nexus 6 (virtual device) its look like my UI does not support different screen sizes. I learned about DP(device independent pixels) that it fit the element for every screen size by default but in this case, it's not working. What should I do now to support it for every device? I attach UI code and pics for more information.

[image: This is the interface when I am working on and it looks good in android studio.]

[image: when I run this code in Nexus 6 it dose not fit. It dose not fit as the previous image in android studio.]

here is the XML layout file. I use Relative Layout as a parent layout and inside relative layout is use multiple Linear layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtResult"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="serif-monospace"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txtResultTextSize" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtOperation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:padding="@dimen/txtOperationPadding"
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/txtOperationTextSize" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBtnDecimals"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutText"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFactorial"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="!"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDel"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="«"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnC"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSqrRoot"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="√"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnForwardBracket"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="("
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnBackwardBracket"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text=")"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="7"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="8"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="9"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="4"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="5"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="6"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="2"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn0Width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="0"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDot"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="."
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/linearLayoutBtnDecimals"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutText"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayoutBtnDecimals"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/linearLayoutBtnDecimals"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDiv"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:background="@color/dark"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="÷"
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMul"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:background="@color/dark"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="×"
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnMinus"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:background="@color/dark"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="-"
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnPlus"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:background="@color/dark"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="+"
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEqual"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btnEqualHeight"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:background="@color/dark"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:text="="
        android:textColor="@color/cyan"
        android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here is the dimens.xml file

```
<dimen name="btnWidth">95dp</dimen>
<dimen name="btnHeight">62dp</dimen>
<dimen name="btn0Width">191dp</dimen>
<dimen name="btnMarginRight">1dp</dimen>
<dimen name="btnTextSize">40sp</dimen>
<dimen name="btnEqualHeight">125dp</dimen>
<dimen name="marginBottom">1sp</dimen>
<dimen name="txtResultTextSize">80sp</dimen>
<dimen name="txtOperationTextSize">30sp</dimen>
<dimen name="txtOperationPadding">5dp</dimen>
```

so what should I do now to set the layout for every screen sizes devices?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you are using fixed size for UI then you have to create different dimen folders according to screen size. Another option is you can use weightSum to layout and manage views(Buttons in your UI) accordingly.

Comment: Use weight sum is best option.

Comment: Simplify your design: Put your buttons in a GridView or in a GridLayout. Be happy with the results.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36264377/responsive-design-for-all-android-devices it may help full

Answer (score 0):

Better use [Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html). You may also consider different **dimens.xml** for different screen types (*you can do this by creating new dimens.xml file with qualifiers like **screen density** & **screen size***) which gets applied to the respective type of screens

Example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score -1):

Never give layout heights match parent to the inner layouts other than the parent layout and instead of giving fixed sizes in dp you can use wrap content for child views(Button, Textviews etc). And also you can use weight sum.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutBtnDecimals"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="**wrap_content**"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutText"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/marginBottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnFactorial"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btnWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btnHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="!"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDel"
            android:layout_width="**wrap_content**"
            android:layout_height="**wrap_content**"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="«"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnC"
            android:layout_width="**wrap_content**"
            android:layout_height="**wrap_content**"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/btnMarginRight"
            android:background="@color/darkGrey1"
            android:fontFamily="monospace"
            android:text="C"
            android:textColor="@color/lightGrey4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/btnTextSize" />
</LinearLayout>
```